# Get request object in webMethods Java service

Tags: java, web-services, service, request, webmethods

Simple question:

- I have a webMethods "REST-Service" (_post).
- Inside the "REST-Service" service I call a self written java service.
- Inside the java service I want to get the raw body of the request.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending on the `Content-Type` header, webMethods chooses a `ContentHandler` to parse the inputs. The raw body can be preserved by such a `ContentHandler`, but it's not done in a uniform way.

example 1, for `Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded`:

```
InvokeState is = InvokeState.getCurrentState();
byte[] bytesIn = (byte[])is.getPrivateData("$msgBytesIn");
String body = null;
if (bytesIn!=null) {
    body = new String(bytesIn, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
}
// body now contains the request body
```

example 2, for `Content-Type: multipart/form-data`:

```
IDataCursor pipelineCursor = pipeline.getCursor();
InputStream bodyStream = (InputStream)IDataUtil.get( pipelineCursor, "contentStream" );
pipelineCursor.destroy();
// bodyStream now contains the request body
```